# LineCollections for few lines with a single colorbar

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot some lines using LineCollection in a plot. Each of these lines is needed to be mapped to colorbar whose range varies for each lines. I tried as explained here

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html?highlight=line%20collection

In the end, I want a single colorbar, for let's say three lines, covering all ranges. However, the colorbar is set for the last line values. So I looked here

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/multi_image.html

But I'm not being successful since I'm quite new to Matplotlib. I paste my code below. I'm just trying to map the value of the lines (also shown on y-axis) in a colorbar for all three lines. Any help is appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import colors

lineSegments = [np.linspace(0,1,10),
                np.linspace(0,5,10),
                np.linspace(0,2,10)]

xVec = np.linspace(0,1,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
    
    
    cValue = np.linspace( min(lineSegments[i]), max(lineSegments[i]) )
    norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=cValue.min(), vmax=cValue.max() )
    
    Points = np.array([xVec, lineSegments[i]]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    PointSegments = np.concatenate([Points[:-1],Points[1:]], axis=1)
    lc = LineCollection(PointSegments, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), 
                        norm=norm) 
    #plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim( min(xVec), max(xVec) ) 
    ax.set_ylim( np.amin(lineSegments), np.amax(lineSegments) )
    lc.set_array(cValue)
 
fig.colorbar(lc)

def update(changed_lines):
    for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
        if (changed_lines.get_cmap() != lc.get_cmap()
            or changed_lines.get_clim() != lc.get_clim()):
          lc.set_cmap(changed_lines.get_cmap())
          lc.set_clim(changed_lines.get_clim())
          
        
for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
    lc.callbacksSM.connect('changed',update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. Essentially what you need to do is create a norm instance for the entire dataset and then assign color values to the segments according to the colormap you have with the given norm. You can then pass it to the colorbar accordingly.

As such

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import colors

lineSegments = [np.linspace(0,1,10),
                np.linspace(0,5,10),
                np.linspace(0,2,10)]

xVec = np.linspace(0,1,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=min([ i.min() for i in lineSegments ]),
                        vmax=max([i.max() for i in lineSegments]))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
    cValue = norm(lineSegments[i])
    c = cmap(cValue)
    Points = np.array([xVec, lineSegments[i]]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    PointSegments = np.concatenate([Points[:-1],Points[1:]], axis=1)
    lc = LineCollection(PointSegments, cmap=cmap,
                        norm=norm, colors = c)
    #plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim( min(xVec), max(xVec) )
    ax.set_ylim( np.amin(lineSegments), np.amax(lineSegments) )
    # lc.set_array(cValue)
sc = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap)
fig.colorbar(sc)

def update(changed_lines):
    for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
        if (changed_lines.get_cmap() != lc.get_cmap()
            or changed_lines.get_clim() != lc.get_clim()):
            lc.set_cmap(changed_lines.get_cmap())
            lc.set_clim(changed_lines.get_clim())


for i in range(0, len(lineSegments)):
    lc.callbacksSM.connect('changed',update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just minor comment, setting color values directly makes the norm and cmap in the linecollection redundant I believe.